# error occurred while trying to display the widget "filter_motion_chart"

Tags: sonarqube

I have sonarqube installed 5.1 with oracle instance and Java 1.8 but i am getting below error. I tried reinstalling motion chart plugin many times but no luck, any idea about issue ?-

```
2015.08.03 06:32:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.TomcatAccessLog] Web server is started
2015.08.03 06:32:32 INFO  web[o.s.s.a.EmbeddedTomcat] HTTP connector enabled on port 8080
2015.08.03 06:32:33 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails] Can not render widget filter_motion_chart: Missing template motion_chart/_widget_body.erb in view path app/views
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/paths.rb:74:in `find_template'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:237:in `_pick_partial_template'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activesupport-2.3.15/lib/active_support/memoizable.rb:122:in `_pick_partial_templ ate'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   compiled-template:8:in `_run_inline_1206365509_locals_dashboard_configuration_widget_widget_properties'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:269:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/helpers/dashboard_helper.rb:162:in `widget_body'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/_widget.html.erb:3:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47_widget46html46e rb_locals_object_widget'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2227:in `send'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:34:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:306:in `with_template'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable.rb:30:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:20:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:30:in `benchmark'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:19:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/template.rb:205:in `render_template'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/renderable_partial.rb:44:in `render_partial'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/partials.rb:184:in `render_partial'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_view/base.rb:267:in `render'
2015.08.03 06:32:39 ERROR web[rails]   /cstg/sonar/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/app/views/dashboard/index.html.erb:19:in `_run_erb_app47views47dashboard47index46html46erb'
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to SonarQube 5.2 fixed this problem for us.